# There is some way to emit older items of a BehaviorSubject

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have a BehaviorSubject like this:

```
private BehaviorSubject<List<Activity>> draft = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(new ArrayList<>());
```

this Subject represent the items in a recyclerView, so when I call the onNext method the some items are added to the recyclerView.

the problem come when the the view is attached again to the screen obviously only the last item emitted is visible on the recyclerView.

So the questions is there is some way to accumulate all items emitted on first subscription?

Regards

Comment: There exist other types of `Subject`s. [See which one](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/package-summary.html) fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to get back the previously emitted items. You have to store it some variable/store which wont change on view attach and detach. If you want to get the previously stored item then this component is not the ideal one to use in your case.

Comment: actually I'm doing that right now, I just think should have a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You are exactly describing a `ReplaySubject`. A `ReplaySubject` will emit all previously emitted values for any new subscriber.

Check the marble diagram [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/ReplaySubject.html).

Comment: Hi, this a posible solution, but is some weird update n times the recyclerView.

Comment: That is because you are updating RecyclerView with each item, it would be better to make your emission be a List instead, of use toList() on your stream